# audio and video data in RTP

Tags: networking, protocol, media

Suppose a user wants to transmit both audio and video to another user, whose formats are AMR for audio and H.264 for video. Does the user have to transmit audio and video packets always separately? Meaning that it is not possible to mix audio and video within the same RTP packed, is that correct?

If this is true I guess the RTP protocol will need to know the SSRC of both audio and video to be able to check the sync of the two streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure proper playback, the audio and video data *MUST* always be multiplexed together along with the timing information. This is done by various container formats like *mp4* or *3gpp* or *mov*.

In the file formats the audio and video data are partitioned in the form of chunks and their time of playout is marked. This allows players to understand when to display video to screen and put the audio samples to speaker - irrespective of how they arrive. Usually there is sufficient buffer to ensure that sufficient time still exists after all network delays to reach the data to rendering even if audio and video has a different amount of delay while transmission.

If you use container formats such as ones mentioned above, RTP doesn't need to know whether particular packet is Audio or Video.

One more thing - SSRC doesn't really provide any crucial *timing information* by itself. It is only a *label*. For example, if i a DVR is receiving data from 16 cameras (and 16 microphones for audio), it needs reference for each such source. This is only an address or identifier not a source of timing information. So if logically, audio and video comes from same source, it can have same tag.

Comment: if they are multiplexed within the same packet, why the need of RTCP for AV sync problems?

Comment: there are so many ways to achieve av sync. Indeed, if you are streaming using MP4 - you *DO NOT* need RTCP for AV sync to be achieved.

Comment: You never need rtcp its used for things mp4 can't tell you like network jitter and time... and should always be enabled.